# How can I print each list item, in a single line of code?

Tags: python

I want to do something like:

`print '  -- Checking connectivity from {} to {}'.format((h for h in env.hosts), (h for h in dbHostList))`

However, this only produces: `-- Checking connectivity from <generator object <genexpr> at 0x2c36190> to <generator object <genexpr> at 0x2c367d0>`

I know there's a way to do this, and I'm just skipping something small.. but I don't know what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: To expand on @user5061's question: what do you want? Are you testing each possible connection and reporting the results?  Are you testing certain pairs? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you want the lists formatted, but you could do

```
print '  -- Checking connectivity from {} to {}'.format(env.hosts, dbHostList)
```

This would create a string like

```
'  -- Checking connectivity from [1, 2, 3] to [4, 5, 6]'
```

Otherwise if you want some particular format/delimiter you could use `join`, for example

```
print '  -- Checking connectivity from {} to {}'.format(':'.join(map(str, env.hosts)), ':'.join(map(str, dbHostList)))
```

Which would print

```
'  -- Checking connectivity from 1:2:3 to 4:5:6'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(for object in sequence)
```

creates a **Generator**. You want this:

```
[for object in sequence]
```

edit:

Or this:

```
print "Stuff stuff stuff {}".format(" ".join(list))
```

Comment: A list comprehension of `[h for h in env.hosts]` would be a complete waste of time. It would create a list, which is an exact copy of `env.hosts` which is already a list.

Comment: True. I thought he just wanted the correct syntax from () to []. The edit will work, though.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if your list items are strings, you can use [string join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print ' '.join(env.hosts)
```

If your list items aren't strings, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in which you call [str()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) (assuming you have a data type that can be converted by str()) to make them strings:

```
print ' '.join([str(h) for h in env.hosts])
```

Comment: You don't need to make a string comprehension, a generator will do.

Comment: While a generator can be made to work, it seems the OP wants to print the whole "thing"; thus nothing is gained using a generator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a line for each check, you can [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) newlines together with a formatted string for each pair of hosts. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can combine the two lists so you can iterate over them pairwise:

```
print '\n'.join('  -- Checking connectivity from {host} to {db_host}'
                .format(host=host, db_host=db_host)
                for host, db_host in zip(env.hosts, dbHostList))
```